# APi de google gmail

Tags: api, gmail, google-api, apigoogle

Quiero saber si es posible ver mis correos de gmail recibidos y enviados desde otra web usando la api de gmail, es decir,
quiero crear una web desde 0 pero en esta web me quiero "loguear" con mi cuenta de gmail, y posteriormente en la misma web, me muestre todos los correo recibidos y demás.

Estoy haciendo un proyecto y un reto de este es poder ver los correos que recibo en gmail desde la app web que estoy creando.

Answer (score 2):

Eh escuchado sobre el tema aquí te dejo el Link para que te documentes de [gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/?hl=es-419)

Entre otras cosas se pude

- enviar email
- ver bandeja
- recibir email
- leer emails

Answer (score -1):

Si, pero necesitas autorizar tu aplicación en [Google](https://console.cloud.google.com/) y luego habilitar el servicio de Gmail para poder usar la API en sí [GMAIL-API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest?hl=es-419)